# Define a pointer with brace in C?

Tags: c, pointers

I saw a part of a sample code like this:

```
1 void func (uint8_t *buffer, uint16_t length)
2 {
3    uint8_t *pack = {0};
4
5    for(int i=0; i<length; i++)
6    {
7       pack[i] = buffer[i];
8    }
9    
10   // send out the "pack" here
11 }
```

This is a function supposed to fill the data in the "buffer" to "pack", and then send the "pack" out to a serial connection.

What does line 3 do? It is like defining a struct with all elements to 0, but it is a pointer here! Where does this pointer point to? In the following for loop, why it can change to an array (pack[i]) and why we do not need to declare the size like:

```
uint8_t pack_array[length], *pack;
*pack = pack_array;
```

The compiler is GCC.

[Edited] : There is a typo in the for loop.

Comment: What's this `for(int i=0; i++; i<length)`???

Comment: From where you get this snippet?

Comment: This code has an obvious semantic error in the for loop and if it hadn't it would invoke undefined behaviour for `length != 0`.

Comment: Sorry all, there is a typo in the original 'for' loop, the order of the expression is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

From the C99 standard, 6.7.8p11:

> The initializer for a scalar shall be a single expression, optionally enclosed in braces.

The term "scalar" refers to arithmetic types and pointers.

So the braces are allowed, and do nothing.

The line `uint8_t *pack = {0};` will initialize the pointer `pack` with the value `0`, so it will be a null pointer.

The following `for` loop is wrong. Both because the order of expressions in it is incorrect, and because the assignment dereferences `pack` which is a null pointer.

Comment: The error of the expression order is my bad. However other lines are equal to the sample code. Thank you very much for helping me to confirm this code is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In your snippet, memory is not allocated for `pack`. Without allocating memory you can't use as subscripted arrays.

```
for(int i=0; i++; i<length)
```

is wrong. `i<length` should be second expression of `for` loop.